# The term '-replace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell

I was editing my powershell script and it suddenly started to give me strange errors:

`-replace : The term '-replace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`

and

`-Get-TfsItemHistory : The term 'Get-TfsItemHistory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`

I would understand the second error, but -replace? Thats strange.

*Get-TfsItemHistory is used in referenced file VersionsCache.ps1*

Script.ps1:

```
   #For all projects, that has been changed since last build updates [AssemblyVersion], [AssemblyFileVersion], and [AssemblyInformationalVersion],  attributes in all assemblyinfo.cs files.
    $rootDir = "C:\Projects\UI\Evis\Dev"
    $version = "2.0.0"
    $buildType = "beta"
    $currentChangeset = 1789
    $versionsCacheFile ="C:\Projects\UI\Evis\versionsCache.txt"

. "$rootDir\VersionsCache.ps1"

$projects = Get-ChildItem "$rootDir\*.csproj" -Recurse;



function UpdateAssemblyInfo{
    Param ([string]$dir, [string]$assemblyVersion, [string]$assemblyInformationalVersion)

    $assemblyVersionPattern = 'AssemblyVersion\("[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+|\*)){1,3}"\)'
    $assemblyFileVersionPattern = 'AssemblyFileVersion\("[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+|\*)){1,3}"\)'
    $assemblyInformationalVersionPattern = 'AssemblyInformationalVersion\(.*\)'

    $newVersion = 'AssemblyVersion("' + $assemblyVersion + '")';
    $newFileVersion = 'AssemblyFileVersion("' + $assemblyVersion + '")';
    $newInformationalVersion = 'AssemblyInformationalVersion("' + $assemblyInformationalVersion + '")';

    $assemblyInfoFile = Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter assemblyinfo.cs -Recurse -Depth 1
    $assemblyInfoContent = (Get-Content $assemblyInfoFile.FullName) 
        -replace $assemblyVersionPattern, $newVersion 
        -replace $assemblyFileVersionPattern, $newVersion


    if ($assemblyInfoContent -match $assemblyInformationalVersionPattern)
    {
        $assemblyInfoContent = $assemblyInfoContent -replace $assemblyInformationalVersionPattern, $newInformationalVersion
    }
    else{
        $assemblyInfoContent = $assemblyInfoContent + "`r`n[assembly: $newInformationalVersion]"
    }

    
    $assemblyInfoContent| Out-File $assemblyInfoFile.FullName
}


$publishedChangesetsCache = Load-Versions $versionsCacheFile

foreach ($project in $projects)
{
    $projectDir = $project.Directory.FullName;

    $assemblyInfo = Get-ChildItem $projectDir -Filter assemblyinfo.cs -Recurse -Depth 1 | select -First 1

    Write-Host $projectDir -NoNewLine

    $publishedChangesets = GetpublishedChangesets -dir $projectDir -publishedChangesetsCache $publishedChangesetsCache
    $latestChangesetId = GetLatestChangeset $dir
    Write-Host "changeset: $latestChangesetId"

    if (IsChangedSinceLastBuild $latestChangesetId $publishedChangesets){
        $publishedChangesets.Insert(0,$currentChangeset)
    }
    $changesetToPublish =  $publishedChangesets[0]
   
    $informationalVersion = "$version.$changesetToPublish"
    if ($buildType -ne ""){
        $informationalVersion = "$version-$buildType$changesetToPublish"
    }
    UpdateAssemblyInfo $projectDir -assemblyVersion "$version.$changesetToPublish" -assemblyInformationalVersion $informationalVersion
}



Save-Versions $publishedChangesetsCache -file versionsCacheFile
```

I guess I have some syntactic error, because it worked yesterday, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add backticks if you want to put the `-replace` statement in a new line:

```
$assemblyInfoContent = (Get-Content $assemblyInfoFile.FullName) `
             -replace $assemblyVersionPattern, $newVersion `
             -replace $assemblyFileVersionPattern, $newVersion
```

Or just write it in one line...